# How can I ignore the first line break for a Positive Lookahead (regex)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the text before matching a certain word ("METROS") and I'm struggling with the line break ("\n"). I only want to ignore the first line break before my match (not the second).

Any suggestions?

Raw Text:
DATOS DEL LUGAR \n
**MIDE UNA SUPERFICIE DE CINCUENTA Y** \n
**NUEVE** METROS CUADRADOS.

Text I want:
**MIDE UNA SUPERFICIE DE CINCUENTA Y
NUEVE**

Regex I am using:

```
([^\\n{1}]\n.*)(?=METROS)
```

My result until now:
**Y 
NUEVE**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
`(^.*\n?.*)(?=METROS)`

Please remove `?` after '\n' if there will be always a newline before `METROS`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could also get the value using a capturing group.

Match optional leading whitespace chars without a newline. Then start the capturing group matching the rest of the line including the newline. On the next line continue capturing what comes before the first occurrence of METROS using a non greedy `.*?` quantifier.

```
^[^\S\r\n]*(.*\r?\n.*?) METROS\b
```

- `^` Start of line
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match optional leading whitespace chars without a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*\r?\n.*?`
- `)` Close group
- `METROS\b` Match a space, METROS followed by a word bounary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j9aFOI/1)

Comment: Gotcha!
I will also keep that alternative in mind, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*\n{1})(.*\n.*)(?=METROS)
```

Regex I could think of off the top of my head (take second group). A bigger example would be helpful if the above doesn't work for you.